# I bought a MP2307 DC-DC converver from eBay. I would like to filter the output, but its has a problem

Tags: dc

[image: Picture]

When I added a ferrite bead and a capacitor to the output to filter it, its get oscillating and doesn't work.

I don't know why? Can't filter the output?

Comment: What does the data sheet of the bought device tell you about what loading conditions might produce an oscillation or instability?

Comment: Then you are looking in the wrong place or at the wrong document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet says: -

> Compensation Node. COMP is used to compensate the regulation control
>   loop. Connect a series RC network from COMP to GND. In some cases, an
>   additional capacitor from COMP to GND is required. See Compensation
>   Components.

It also says: -

> The system has two poles of importance. One is due to the compensation
>   capacitor (C3) and the output resistor of the error amplifier, and the
>   other is due to the output capacitor and the load resistor

And...

> The system may have another zero of importance, if the output
>   capacitor has a large capacitance and/or a high ESR value.

And...

> Determine if the second compensation capacitor (C6) is required. It is
>   required if the ESR zero of the output capacitor is located at less
>   than half of the switching frequency

The bottom line is that you probably need to add a further capacitor shown as C8 in your circuit (referred to as C6 in the data sheet). Read the data sheet and note the circuit contained below: -

[image]

Your schematic shows more output capacitance than the one above. Also note that using a ferrite bead of the type indicated will not be of any use for controlling the ripple voltages. You should try using an inductor instead.